# What does grub-install's --removable flag do?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

GRUB2's `grub-install` has a `--removable` flag, but all the man page says is that it signifies "the installation device is removable."  The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) likewise just says "For removable installs you have to use --removable."  What does GRUB actually do differently with/without this setting?  (For context, I found this while trying to understand the arguments required to fix my GRUB install on a UEFI system, and found [some discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/sb736l/comment/htyx39i/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) about that specific option.)

Comment: It install the EFI executable to the "fallback" path (e.g. `EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`) to avoid having to register the executable to the UEFI firmware (NVRAM). The UEFI firmware will list it automatically (as a "disk" entry).

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) as well, particularly the first two paragraphs of `The EFI Boot Process`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!  I'll mark this accepted it you put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It installs the EFI executable to the "fallback" path (e.g. `EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`) to avoid having to register the executable to the UEFI firmware (NVRAM). The UEFI firmware will list it automatically (as a "disk" entry).

source: a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1756758/what-does-grub-installs-removable-flag-do#comment2729280_1756758) in the question.

> The fallback boot loader mentioned earlier (`EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`, or variants of that, depending on the architecture) is something of a special case. This filename was originally intended for use only on removable media, so that they could be booted to install an OS. (If not for that fixed filename, a factory-fresh computer wouldn't be able to boot anything!) This filename was quickly adopted as a fallback filename for hard disk installations, as well. This way, if a duplicate of the normal boot loader is installed to the fallback filename, the computer will remain bootable if the NVRAM-based boot manager list is damaged.

[source](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html), referenced in another comment.

Also check the [default names](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/03_Boot_Manager.html#removable-media-boot-behavior) for other architectures.